# clojure loop/recur in a range

Tags: loops, clojure

I want to do a `loop/recur` in a range of 3 to 11:

```
(loop [itr 3]
  (if (and (< itr 11) (= 0 (mod itr 4)))
    (println itr)
    (recur (inc itr))
    ))
```

As expected, it will return `4`. The problem is when I am looking for something that doesn't have any match:

```
(loop [itr 2]
  (if (and (< itr 3) (= 0 (mod itr 4)))
    (println itr)
    (recur (inc itr))
    ))
```

This will crash the REPL without returning the `nil`. Is there a way to add something like an `else` statement to this loop, so if there is no match, it returns a `nil`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `loop`/`recur`, consider using the higher-level functions at your disposal:

```
(first (filter #(zero? (mod % 4)) (range 3 11)))
;=> 4
(first (filter #(zero? (mod % 4)) (range 2 3)))
;=> nil
```